# Hat matrix for penalized spline

Tags: splines, smoothing

Suppose the penalized spline given by equation
$$
\hat{x}=(W+\lambda_{1}D^{T}D+2\lambda_{2})^{-1}\left[Wy+\lambda_{2}(A+B)\right],
$$
where $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}$ are positive constants and $A,B$
are linear constraints. My questions:

1. How to construct the hat matrix for this formula?
2. Is there any kind of ``generalized'' GVC determining optimal values
   of 2 parameters $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}$ (2D version of classical
   GVC)?

The hat matrix has the general form of
$$
\widehat{x}=Hy.
$$
If
$$
M=(W+\lambda_{1}D^{T}D+2\lambda_{2})^{-1},
$$
then the hat matrix depends on $y$
$$
H=MW+\lambda_{2}M(A+B)y^{-1}.
$$
How to continue? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Unless $\lambda_2(A+B)=0,$ there is no matrix $H$ (independent of $y$) for which $\hat x = Hy.$

Comment: @whuber: Since there is no matrix $H$ independent of $y$, is it impossible to use GCV?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "use GCV."  All you ask is how to "construct a hat matrix."  The answer is, that makes no sense because there is no hat matrix.  That's all.